# Load cell simulator-mV/volt generation

Tags: signal, potentiometer, load-cell, strain-gage

I am trying to simulate a full bridge sensor load cell.

Here is the reff to the image: https://www.scribd.com/doc/140674267/Load-Cell-Simulator-v2

[image]

Above is the reff circuit I am using. I know that making a bridge circuit like this one below would work, but I am not able to get the potentiomenter to get the bridge slightly unbalanced (0.1%) so that I can measure a 25mV/volt generated in signal + and signal-.

I built the above circuit, but I didn't have 3.3M in 1/2 watt.  I think for this reason changing R5 for the full span is giving just 5mv/volt output. The excitation voltage is 5volt.

Can anyone help me generate 25mv/volt output from the circuit?

Image Reff:https://www.engineeringclicks.com/wheatstone-bridge/

[image]

Comment: Altroz - Hi, Please note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source references (source name & link) for each copied image & remember to include references in future. Thanks. || As you're new here, please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help].

Comment: @SamGibson I have updated the question

Comment: Altroz - Thanks for the first link; although that site is tricky to use, I see that image there. However I looked at the [second page you linked](https://www.engineeringclicks.com/wheatstone-bridge/), and the [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvrEI.jpg) is not shown on that page. Please check and provide the correct source link for that second image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use much lower value precision resistors for R1/R4 and shunt the pot element with a low value precision resistor.

For example, if you use 10kΩ 1% resistors then to get 125mV across the pot (current of 4.875V/20kΩ =  0.244mA) you'd need a shunt resistor of about 540Ω. 549Ω 1% is a standard  E96 series value. This is just calculated from Ohm's law, and you can do the same if you want a different voltage span.

Comment: i dont think my issue is tha span, i need to het 25 Mv at the output of signal + and -

Comment: This will give you 0 to 125mV (polarity depends on which way it is connected). So 25mV/V as you requested.